# Angular checkboxes and ng-repeat not showing up in model

Tags: angularjs

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'd like the value of checkboxes to show up as an array in the stores property. Nothing ever shows up.  I feel like I'm not utilizing the ng-model properly.

**Controller**

```
$scope.parameters = {
        myMainOptions:
        {
            teams: ['angels', 'giants', 'orioles', 'bluejays', 'athletics']
        }
}
```

**View**

```
<li ng-repeat="t in parameters.myMainOptions.teams">
   <input ng-model="form.selectedTeams[t]" type="checkbox" /> {{t}}
</li>

<button class="btn btn-sm" type="submit" ng-click="submit(form)">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Answer (score 1):

you will need to initialize an array in scope to fill the data into it,,
and also you need to use **$index** to access the current index of each element ,, so that you can make it as an array not with the object is sel as key like here

```
<input ng-model="boxes[$index]" type="checkbox" />
```

you can see the js fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/vrem17m0/

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in your code. Just make sure to initialize the `form.selectedTeams` object and set the angular controller correctly, then you should be good to go.

You can check this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/walterr/1rw95wt8/) to see it working.